# Properties of custom control can only be filled by StaticResource but not with values defined in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, controls

I've created my own `ExpandableView` based on this https://www.clearpeople.com/insights/blog/2019/February/how-to-create-a-contentview-with-expandable-functionality
but as all C# code.

My control looks like this (without the animation part)

```
public class ExpandableView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ExpandableContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ExpandableContent), typeof(View), typeof(ExpandableView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TitleText), typeof(string), typeof(ExpandableView));


    public View ExpandableContent
    {
        get => this._content;
        set
        {
            if (this._content == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            OnPropertyChanging();
            if (this._content != null)
            {
                this._ContentLayout.Children.Remove(this._content);
            }
            this._content = value;
            this._ContentLayout.Children.Add(this._content);

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string TitleText
    {
        get => this._Title.Text;
        set
        {
            if (this._Title.Text == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            OnPropertyChanging();
            this._Title.Text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private readonly StackLayout _OuterLayout;
    private readonly StackLayout _ContentLayout;
    private readonly StackLayout _TitleLayout;
    private View _content;
    private readonly Label _Title;

    public ExpandableView()
    {
        this._OuterLayout = new StackLayout();

        this._ContentLayout = new StackLayout();
        this._TitleLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        };

        this._Title = new Label
        {
            HorizontalOptions = new LayoutOptions(LayoutAlignment.Start, true),
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            Text = "Title",
        };
        this._Title.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, this._Title);

        this._TitleLayout.Children.Add(this._Title);

        this._OuterLayout.Children.Add(this._TitleLayout);
        this._OuterLayout.Children.Add(this._ContentLayout);

        Content = this._OuterLayout;
    }
}
```

But now, when I try to use it in XAML as I normally would:

```
<controls:ExpandableView TitleText="Equipment">
    <controls:ExpandableView.ExpandableContent>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="EQ_12345" />
            <Button Command="{Binding ShowDatacommand}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </controls:ExpandableView.ExpandableContent>
</controls:ExpandableView>
```

Setting the properties to some values results in the title still showing me "Title" and no content being shown. If I instead put everything into the `StaticResource` Everything works just fine:

```
<controls:ExpandableView ExpandableContent="{StaticResource ExpendableViewContent}"
                         TitleText="{StaticResource EquiString}" />
```

While testing, I set some breakpoints within the properties, and only when I used `{StaticResource}` the properties were set. All values defined directly in XAML were never passed to the properties. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining your own BindableProperty properties, the definitive source for the values is expected to be accessed via BindableObject.SetValue/BindableObject.GetValue.  The Xamarin runtime can directly use that rather than going through your get/set methods.

Using TitleText as an example, the implementation should be something like:

```
public string TitleText
{
    get => (string)GetValue(TitleTextProperty);
    set
    {
        SetValue(TitleTextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

The linked article does do this.

In order to create the link between the property and the displayed title, establish data binding in the constructor to link the Text of the title label to the TitleText property in the ExpandableView constructor:

```
_Title.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(TitleText)) { Source = this });
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine now. Had to use a `ContentView` instead of a `View` for `_Content` so I could bind the property `ExpendableContent` to it and attach it permanently to the `_ContentLayout`. Thanks again.